# Regex accept numeric only. First character can't be 0

Tags: regex

I have a textbox that I created using .NET..

By using that textbox, the user only can key in numeric. But not start with 0. start with 1-9. after the user key in the 1-9 at the first character, the user can key in 0.

```
Regex reg = null;
reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^[1-9][0-9]*$")
return reg.IsMatch(str);
```

That is my regex expression. By using that i can't key in 1-9. but only 0 and alphabet. 
But if i using ^[1-9] I can key in numeric, but can't key in the 0.

I already tried all the answer that all of you suggest. But still can't work. It's not like i dont read all of your answer.

here is the picture..

[image]

I want to validate at the first time, the user only can key in numeric, but start with value that is not 0 or alphabet but 1-9. After the first character, user may only key in 0-9.

i do use Int.TryParse, but i use that after i hit a button to process.

```
reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^[^0-9]");
```

that regex accept only numeric from 0 to 9.

```
reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^[^1-9]");
```

that regex accept only numeric from 1 to 9.

How can i add more expression to regex for the second character until the rest that only accept numeric 0-9?

By the way, i don't care about 0.99 because in here, the price is fix. not with 0.99 or 0.123..

Any others way to do it? thanks.

Comment: Any regex to start with? Or is `^($|[^0])` an acceptable solution?

Comment: for example i have to key in price.. user can't key in the price start with 0. they have to key in value between 1-9 at the first character, for the second character until the rest 0-9 is allowed.. do you know what is the regex syntax? thanks.

Comment: Again, should `hello` be accepted? It doesn't start with a zero.

Comment: @JanDvorak - rejected. only numeric.

Comment: You did not say "only numeric" in the original question.

Comment: Alfred, keep in mind that `0.99` is a perfectly valid (and heavily used, due to app stores) price.

Comment: Hi paxdiablo, thanks for your information. But this is a textbox. i want to validate user can't key in a numeric that start with 0, but start with 1-9. after the first character then they can key in 0-9. any idea how to doint this?

Comment: There are already 3 good answer Alfred. Why don't you read them?

Comment: Since I seriously doubt I will ever know for sure what the asker actually wants, I vote to close as "not a real question".

Comment: You could have used [Int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) here

Comment: Thats mean user can key in a value that start wih 0?

Answer (score 55):

If you're looking at something like a price, you need to consider that `0.99` is probably perfectly valid. For something like that, I would simply start with a non-complex `^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$` (again there may be edge cases that may make it more complex like three digits after the decimal point and so on) and *allow* leading zeroes, since they don't "damage" the value in anyway.

It it *must* start with a non zero, just change the initial `[0-9]*` to a `[1-9][0-9]*`. For integers only (as seems to be indicated by your added sample data), that would be:

```
^[1-9][0-9]*$
```

Answer (score 26):

To match a number starting with any digit but zero:

```
^[1-9][0-9]*$
```

And if you want to match 0 as well:

```
^([1-9][0-9]*)|([0]+)$
```

remove the last plus if you want a single zero only

To allow any alpha-numeric after first non-zero:

```
^[1-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]*$
```

Comment: Normally, a lone zero is desired to be matched as well.

Comment: depending on the language, they might be non-capturing groups as I intended.

Comment: @JanDvorak when did op say lone zero to be matched as well?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im never did he (yet). He didn't say anything about rejecting letters either.

Comment: @JanDvorak but perreal has changed his answer for your uncertain assumption.

Comment: @perreal he didn't say numeric in the first revision.

Comment: try this before. 0 and alphabet is allowed. but i can't key in 1-9.

Comment: @AlfredAngkasa "alphabet is allowed" -- WTH? You _want_ letters to be accepted? This _will not_ accept letters.

Comment: @AlfredAngkasa **Alphabet is A-Z,a-z**. **digit is 0-9**.

Comment: yeah i know..but here still can allowed to key in alphabet. I only want numeric but not start with 0.. i already try ^[1-9][0-9]*$.. still can allowed. why should i lie to all of you that this can still allowed?

Comment: @AlfredAngkasa, perhaps you have a problem with the language/tool you are using and not with the regex. The thing should not allow anything that your regex does not match.

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked the best for me:

```
^(?!(0))[0-9]+$
```

Comment: This only works for single character numbers. like 1,2,3 but not 100, 200, 300 etc.

Comment: Thanks, is use this `(?!0)\d+`

Answer (score 1):

As your code is .NET you **should not use regex to parse an Integer**. Just use [UInt32.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint32.tryparse.aspx) method

```
uint num=0;
if(UInt32.TryParse(str, out num)){
    Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", str, num);   
}else{
    Console.WriteLine("conversion of '{0}' failed.", value==null? "": value);
}
```

#### Old answer

This simple regular expression will do it `^[1-9]\d*$`

Comment: What about the empty string? This will reject the empty string.

Comment: OP didn't say anything about it.

Comment: But how about if user key in 0123556? Because the user can't key in 0 at he first character. How can i handle this? Thanks..

Comment: What is the problem with `0`? its still a valid number. It'll be converted to `123556` after you use `TryParse`

Comment: Hi, i just upload a picture for more clearly. For the first time, whenever user key in the value at the textbox, the user can only key in all numeric but not start with 0. If i key in 0123456 after i hit button, i do convert using Int.TryParse..

Comment: I think your code has other problem. `^[1-9]\d*$` is enough for this. IT'll match `1`, `12`, `10`. In fact at least one digit but leading digit can not be `0`.

Answer (score 1):

This regex accepts numbers `0-9`, doesn't allow `0` to be the first character and also allows the value to be `""`, this is useful for creating `fake` number inputs.

```
^(?!0)[0-9]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

```
^(([1-9]\d*)|([0]{1}))(\.\d+)?$
```

Which also accepts decimals like these numbers:

```
423423.423423

0.4234

0
```

Answer (score 0):

**Input does not start with a zero, you can modify the regular expression to exclude the case where the input starts with zero. Here's an updated regex pattern:**

```
Regex:- ^(?!0)[0-9]*$
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes the regex wont even work in certain browsers. Therefore here is a similar logic:

```
function name(e)
{

var key = window.event ? e.keyCode : e.which;
var keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);
var reg = /\d/;

var textField=document.getElementById("ID").value;

if(key==48)
{
if(textField==""||textField==null)
{
e.preventDefault();
return false;
}

else{
return true;
}
}

else
{
var reg = /\d/;
return reg.test(keychar);
}
}
```