# Indian pincode validation regex - Only six digits, shouldn't start with `0`

Tags: javascript, regex, validating

I have tried [Regex accept numeric only. First character can't be 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132404/regex-accept-numeric-only-first-character-cant-be-0) and [What is the regex for "Any positive integer, excluding 0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036324/what-is-the-regex-for-any-positive-integer-excluding-0) however that didn't work as per my requirements.

I want exact 6 digit numeric number but shouldn't start with `0`

I've tried

```
^[1-9][0-9]{6}*$
^([^0][0-9]){6}$
...
```

Need fine tuning.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The problem with `^[1-9][0-9]{6}*$` is it is an **invalid regex** because of `{6}*` and `^([^0][0-9]){6}$` is that it is allowing any character that is not `0` followed by **six** digits.

Use

```
^[1-9][0-9]{5}$
```

**Explanation:**

1. `^`: Starts with anchor
2. `[1-9]`: Matches exactly one digit from 1 to 9
3. `[0-9]{5}`: Matches exactly five digits in the inclusive range `0-9`
4. `$`: Ends with anchor

[image: Regex Visualization]

[**Regex101 Playground**](https://regex101.com/r/rC2qH1/1)

**HTML5 Demo:**

```css
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="[1-9][0-9]{5}" />
```

Comment: The problem with `^[1-9][0-9]{6}*$` is that it's an invalid regex

Answer (score 3):

This regular expression covers;

1. PIN code doesn't start from zero
2. Allows 6 digits only
3. Allows 6 consecutive digits (e.g. 431602)
4. Allows 1 space after 3 digits (e.g. 431 602)

```
([1-9]{1}[0-9]{5}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{3}\\s[0-9]{3})
```

Answer (score 0):

Some websites and banks have the habit of spacing pincode after 3 digits.
To match both 515411 and 515 411 the following pattern will help.

```
^[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2}\s{0,1}[0-9]{3}$
```

- ^[1-9]{1} - PIN Code that starts with digits 1-9
- [0-9]{2}  - Next two digits may range from 0-9
- \s{0,1}   - Space that can occur once or never
- [0-9]{3}$ - Last 3 needs to be digits ranging from 0-9

Comment: `{1}` can be removed. You can write `\s{0,1}` as `\s?`.

Comment: yeah {1} can be removed. but if you remove ```\s{0,1}``` , The space will be taken as mandatory